# Simulate camera output on iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, xcode-ui-testing

I'm currently trying to implement UI tests in my iOS app. An important feature of my app is the ability to let users scan QR codes so they can quickly retrieve the ID's of certain objects. I'm struggling to write tests for this however. What I would like to achieve is to supply mock images to the camera during UI testing so I can essentially simulate the scanning action. So far I haven't really been able to find anything that mentions whether it is even possible to supply image data to the camera, let alone how this would be implemented.

So my question is, is this even possible?

Comment: You can mock UIImagePickerController and implement the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate returning the mocked images you would like to test.

Comment: @TodorBrachkov I'm not really sure how that relates to simulating what the camera sees?